# what are the appropriate date and time prepositions

Tags: prepositions

In English you can meet
**at** a time (*We will meet at 4pm*.)
**on** a date (*We will meet on the 4th*.)
or be **on** time.

Esperanto doesn't seem to have quite the same rules. 
Is it *en* a date and *je* a time? What about being "on time" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you use *je* for a time and the *-n* suffix for a date. Eg:

> Ni renkontiĝu je la 4a posttagmeze / je la 16a → *Let’s meet at 4pm*
>
> Ni renkontiĝu la 4an (de januaro) → *Let’s meet on the 4th (of January)*

There is more detailed information about [times](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/horoj.html) and [dates](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/datoj.html) in PMEG.

I think you would only use *en* if you are talking about a non-specific point within a certain time range. Eg,

> Ni renkontiĝu en januaro → *Let’s meet (at some point) in January*

PMEG has some [information](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/lokaj_rolvortetoj/en.html#i-sb8) about this too.

For “on time” you can say *ĝustatempe*.

> Venu ĝustatempe aŭ ni maltrafos la komencon de la filmo.

Answer (score 1):

Both `je` and the accusative `-n` (without preposition) are correct for specific points in time, indiscriminate for times and dates. The accusative also for other prepositions like `dum`. The preposition `en` is used too, for a point inside a larger range.

```
esti ĝustatempe = to be on time

dum la oka de marto ne forgesu gratuli vian edzinon = on the 8th of March do not forget
                                                      to wish your wife well
dum la tria horo ili dormis = they slept around three
```

The preposition `dum` for what actually is a period.

```
dum la semajno = in/during the week
en la semajno = at some point in the week
```

The usage of `dum` seems preferable, but `en` is found too. The distinction above I just made up, and is not prescriptive.

Other prepositions:

```
post tempo = in time all will become alright
```